# Can a Visual Studio Code Task generate a file and automatically open it in the same window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have a C# task that generates a file within my VSCode workspace folder.

I would like the file to open automatically after it has been generated. Currently the best I have been able to do is print the full name of the file so the user can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click on the link.

Environment setup:

- Open VSCode in an empty folder.
- Create a new C# console app (type `dotnet new console` in the terminal).
- Update `Program.cs`:

```
namespace VSCodeOpenGeneratedFile
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            File.WriteAllText("test.txt", "Hello world!");
            Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.txt"));
        }
    }
}
```

- Add `.vscode/tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Generate File",
            "command": "dotnet run",
            "type": "shell",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

- Run the task:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
  - Select **Tasks: Run Task**
  - Select **Generate File**
- In the **TERMINAL** you should see the file name, which you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click to open.

How do I have the task automatically open this file instead?

Comment: Your task could try to invoke `code "full/path/to/test.txt"` in a terminal. However even if it is possible I think this would open the `test.txt` in a new vscode instance.

Answer (score 2):

I found that you can accomplish this with the [command line arguments for VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line). Using the `-r` or `--reuse-window` argument, you can have a file open in your current VS code window.

I was able to do this after creating a dated markdown file with this task:

```
{
  "label": "new note",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "set -lx t (date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S);echo \"# $t\" > ${workspaceFolder}/notes/$t.md;code -r ${workspaceFolder}/notes/$t.md"
}
```

This is on Linux with the fish shell, but you should be able to use a similar command for Windows or other shells.